# JQuery, Javascript, AJAX POST json to rest api

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, rest

I have a problem with posting data to a REST API, it should be done like this:

```
curl -X POST -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
 -d '{"event":{"title":"event", "description": "nice", "start": "2018-03-11T22:00:00.000Z"}}' \
 http://events.restdesc.org/events
```

I have the following code:

```
function eventedit(request){
    console.log(request);
    var title = $("#title").val();
    var desc = $("#desc").val();
    var start = $("#start").val();
    start += ".000Z";
    $.ajax({
        url: request,
        type: "POST",
        dataType:'json',
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(error){
            console.log("Something went wrong", error);
        }
    });
}
```

Like you see, I need to add data in my ajax request, but I don't know how to do it, do I need to make a string containing those values? Or an array?

Comment: create an object.

Comment: in your ajax `data: {"title":"event", "description": "nice", "start": "2018-03-11T22:00:00.000Z"}`

Comment: which in your case would be `data: {"title":title, "description": desc, "start": start}` assuming your title, description, and start variables are correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `$.ajax` call add `data`.

```
 $.ajax({
    url: request,
    type: "POST",
    data: {"event":{"title": title, "description": desc, "start": start}},
    dataType:'json',
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(error){
        console.log("Something went wrong", error);
    }
});
```

for `POST` you can also use a shorthand `$.post`

```
  $.post(request, {"event":{"title": title, "description": desc, "start": start}}, function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: what about the "event" like  in this example -> '{"event":{"title":"event", "description": "nice", "start": "2018-03-11T22:00:00.000Z"}}'

Comment: @fangio do you need event?

Answer (score 0):

Just use it like this if you're making a POST

```
$.post(request, {title: title, description: desc, start: start}, function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```